# Всплывающая подсказка к картинке на js

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, html5

Всем привет!
Мне нужно написать такую функцию на `js` или `jQuery`, чтобы при наведении на картинку снизу всплывал блок с текстом. текст для каждой картинку брался из атрибута `alt`. но самое главное, что бы никаких доп элементов не создавать рядом с картинкой (`span`, `div` и т.д.)  
Это вообще возможно?))

Comment: Так а проблема в чем? Создайте один элемент где-нибудь на странице, в который будете выводить текст подсказки и позиционируйте его под соответствующим элементом.

Или же вы просто хотели узнать, возможно ли это? Тогда ответ простой - да ))

Comment: А на css уже никак? http://htmlbook.ru/blog/vsplyvayushchaya-podskazka-na-css

Answer (score 4):

Ниже я приведу пример как осуществить данную задачу на **jQuery**:

Создадим нашу картинку:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src='..' id='image' alt='Вот эта штука есть картинка :)'>
        </td>
        <td class='mess'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ну а дальше **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#image').hover(function(){
        $('.mess').text($('#image').attr('alt'));
    }, function(){
        $('.mess').text('');
    });
});
```

*div,span* не использовал :P

Comment: Если помог, галочку, пожалуйста, поставьте)

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что стоит гуглить что-то вроде "jQuery Tooltip Plugin".

Например: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Как раз в этом примере видно всплывающее окошко.